# Doing synchronous calls when dispatcher's PushFrame is used

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, synchronization, dispatcher

I'm working on a plugin for .Net WPF application which uses the frame pushing technique to achieve 'responsible' UI. Each long-running task in its SDK calls the code:

```
  public static void Wait(Task task)
  {
        DispatcherFrame nestedFrame = new DispatcherFrame();
        task.ContinueWith(delegate { return nestedFrame.Continue = false; });
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(nestedFrame);
        task.Wait();
  }
```

So the typical SDK's method can be emulated by the following code:

```
  private void SdkMethod()
  {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
        });

        Wait(t);
  }
```

It causes a situation when I can not do two synchronous calls to the SDK's methods from the UI thread:

```
  private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
        this.sdk.SdkMethod();
        this.sdk.SdkMethod();
  }
```

Is there any way to synchronize calls in such a situation? I cannot modify SDK, only my own calls to it.

Comment: @MickyD, It's a legacy .Net 4.0 based system and I can not change what is inside SDK.
I understand it can be achieved easily with proper async/await and fully sync SDK calls but I'm limited.

Comment: @MickyD, Thanks for your response. But I need synchronous calls for this particular case, not asynchronous. I'm using async/awaits and tasks a lot across my plugin, the question is not about them.

Comment: @MickyD `SdkMethod` is out of control of OP, he cannot change it.

Comment: @MickyD, SdkMethod and Wait are not mine, I post them to demonstrate what is inside SDK and what does not let my calls be sync.

Comment: "It causes a situation when I can not do two synchronous calls" - why, what happens, what goes wrong?

Comment: @Evk, It's expected that result of the first call should be used for the second one on a server-side. The solution design and architecture are 'as is', they leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: @Evk, Actually the second call starts before the first one completes its work.

Comment: Ewww...it's essentially calling the two methods by serialising them over the message pump.  You better hope your code doesn't become reentrant.  _"[The following example shows how to use a DispatcherFrame to achieve similar results as the Windows Forms **DoEvents** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherframe(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks)"_.   So I'm not sure how you are going to check that the first call is complete

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly from reading the post and comments, you want to call SdkMethod and have it act synchronously. It's being called without letting you know when it is done.

If it is a void method and it isn't a task, you aren't going to get anything in return. I tried to listen to the Dispatcher Hooks for completion, but that was not helpful.

I'd create an aysnc Task method that has a Task.Delay then await it between calls. That way you aren't interrupting the user, but you still force the call to be paused until you call the second method.

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.sdk.SdkMethod();
    await DelayAsync(3).ConfigureAwait(false);
    this.sdk.SdkMethod();
}

private async Task DelayAsync(int seconds)
{
    await Task.Delay(seconds * 1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I hope this helps.